# What's the difference between gnab/rtl8812au on GitHub and rtl8812au-dkms in my package manager?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

So I was updating and installing everything on my new dual-boot setup and noticed that Info Center (or something with its icon) was pushing me to install rtl8812au-dkms for my WiFi even though I had the one from gnab/rtl8812au already installed and working. My question is what's the difference between the two and should I install one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest difference between a dkms driver, and non-dkms drivers, is that dkms drivers will automatically rebuild themselves whenever you do a `Software Update` and the Ubuntu kernel gets updated. Non-dkms drivers usually stop working after a kernel upgrade, and will require a manual recompile and re-installation.

To see if you're running a dkms driver version, or not, use this `terminal` command...

```
dkms status
```

You'll see something like this...

```
r8168, 8.046.00, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

To manually determine if you're running a dkms version, look in `/usr/src` and see if you see a folder of the driver software, and if it contains a `dkms.conf` file, then it's a dkms driver.

```
~$ ls /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.20
clean      hal          Kconfig   platform               regdb
core       ifcfg-wlan0  Makefile  README.md              runwpa
dkms.conf  include      os_dep    Realtek_Changelog.txt  wlan0dhcp
```

Another difference could be that the github driver patches an error, or adds more hardware compatibility. Check the version info in the README file on github.

**Update #1:**

1. The Synaptic rtl8812au-dkms driver version is 4.3.8.12175 from 2014.

   - this requires a modification to the **make** command in **dkms.conf** to:

     `MAKE="'make' KVER=${kernelver}"`
2. The gnab/rtl8812au driver version is based on 4.2.2 from 2013.
3. A better/newer rtl8812au version is [here](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.20) and it's version 5.2.20.

Comment: In addition to @heynnema 's excellent answer, as newer devices are shipped, their repective usb.ids are added to later versions of the driver. Therefore, a device that was released in 2016 would not be driven by the circa-2013 driver version 4.2.2. Also, the older versions will likely not compile properly on later, i.e. 4.15.0-xx kernels.

Comment: Is dkms working in rtl8812au-dkms?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: It had the issue with dkms.conf causing the new module to be built on the old headers which caused exec format error, vermagic didn't match the kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 Change the make command in dkms.conf to `MAKE="'make' -j$PROCS_NUM KVER=${kernelver} KSRC=/lib/modules/${kernelver}/build"`, or even `MAKE="'make' KVER=${kernelver}"` should do. I'd use the newer version anyway.